# In a list of integers, how to subtract a number from one of the elements, if it doesnt meet a condition

Tags: python

I have a list of integers and I want to subtract 26 from any of the elements if they are greater than 27.
For example: if one of the list elements was 32, it would return (32-26)=6 because it is greater than 27.

So say I had a list of integers
    list1=[4,34,56,20...]
How could I check each value in turn to see if it exceeds 27 and then subtract 26 to form a new list??

Thanks :)

Comment: Would you want 56 to turn into 29 or 2?

Comment: And, of course, have you tried anything? SO isn't a coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for any value greate than 27 you could iterate over the list and check where it's greater and only then subtract 26 from the item:

```
new_list = []
for item in your_list:
    if item > 27:
        new_list.append(item - 26)  # appends the reduced item.
    else:
        new_list.append(item)  # append the item without change.
```

or if you want to subtract 26 as long as it's above 27 you could do that with:

```
new_list = []
for item in your_list:
    while item > 27:
        item -= 26
    new_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1=[4,34,56,20]
>>> new_list = [item - 26 if item > 27 else item for item in list1]
>>> new_list
[4, 8, 30, 20]
```

You might be thinking "but wait, I want to subtract 26 from 56 until it's smaller than 28, so it should be 4, not 30". In which case, you could use modular arithmetic.

```
>>> list1=[4,34,56,20]
>>> new_list = [((item-2)%26)+2 for item in list1]
>>> new_list
[4, 8, 4, 20]
```